# Which function similar to math.ceil() works with pyomo?

Tags: pyomo

I need help to make a constraint that round a variable up: what math.ceil() function does. The problem is I'm using pyomo for an optimization model.

The constraint I made:

```
def Trucks(model,i):
  return math.ceil(model.C[i])
model.trucks = Constraint(model.I, Trucks)
```

( model.I=RangeSet(n) )

I expected model.C rounded up
I got "Implicit conversion of Pyomo numeric value (C[1]) to float is disabled.
This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as arguments to
one of the Python built-in math module functions when defining
expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math functions or
explicitly resolving the numeric value using the Pyomo value() function."

Answer (score 0):

`ciel` is a non-linear function that you cannot incorporate into a `pyomo` model.  If the variable `C` should be an integer, just change the variable type to integer and it should work fine.

Comment: The thing is I need the variable to be rounded to the top number

Comment: That will naturally happen if you have constraints on the variable.